# Don't sort inside an enum field

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, enums, code-formatting

How can I disable  sorting values in an enum in eclipse 3.7? I rely on the order of the enum entries, so this breaks my neck every time I hit sort.

`enum X {C,B,A}` turns into `enum X {A,B,C}` after hitting sort members.

Comment: Can you be more explicit and add some code examples please?

Comment: Enum.values() gives them in the order they are declared.  Is this a problem with code formatting changing the declaration order?

Comment: see edit, the code formatter of ecplise changes the declariation order, that is what I want to disable

Comment: There's a dialog box that pops up that lets you exclude "fields, enum constants and initializers."  If you clicked the "Do not show this message again" checkbox, it won't ask you anymore and I have no idea how to get it back.

Comment: I have an enum which references itself B(A), in that case Eclipse sort members breaks the declaration order and the program will not compile anymore. I do the sort members manually via the Source menu (not via save actions), is there a way to avoid sorting enums in that case ? How can I get this dialog box back ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > Additional
>   Actions > Configure > Members > Sort Members > Select "Ignore Fields
>   and Enum constants"

or

> Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Clean Up > Edit > Code Organizing > Members > Sort Members > Select "Ignore Fields and Enum constants"

But you really shouldn't code based on the order the enums are declared. It's simply wrong.

Comment: But it could be useful for organizing the code. So, thank you and +1.

Answer (score 3):

Stop relying on the ordering of the enum entries.  This will cause more bugs than you care to deal with.

By coding to be dependent on the ordering of the enum, you are implicitly calling the enum class's `ordinal()` function (which returns an int).  This has the following drawbacks:

1. It is a maintenance nightmare.  If someone else (or eclipse) reorders your enums, your whole program needs to be reviewed for impact.
2. You cannot add multiple enums with the same int value.
3. You have to insert dummy enums that correspond to no legitimate function to arrive at the desired `ordinal()` return value.
4. You cannot insert enums at arbitrary points within the list without breaking the ordinal mapping, likewise you cannot remove enums.

Instead, expand your enum to properly contain a value, like so:

```
public enum Departments {
   SALES(101),
   ACCOUNTING(200),
   MANAGEMENT(300);

   private final int deptNumber;

   Departments(int number) {
     deptNumber = number;
   }

   public int departmentNumber() {
     return deptNumber;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think relying on position dependent code is a good idea. Since `Enums` can be considered classes in Java why don't you define your specific id?

```
enum Enum
{
    A(0),
    B(1),
    C(2);

    public final int id;
    Enum(int id) { this.id = id; };
}
```

This will be much safer.

Answer (score 0):

I use an exception to detect if I have inadvertently changed the order of the enumerations:

```
enum Enum
{
    A(0),
    B(1),
    C(2);

    private Enum(int ordinal)
    {
        if (this.ordinal() != ordinal)
        {
            throw new BadEnumerationException(ordinal);
        }
    }
}
```